# How to make individuals be a list of variable length in DEAP

Tags: python, deap

I was looking at the [Knapsack example](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/examples/ga_knapsack.html), and I would like to transpose it to the case where individuals are represented by lists rather than by sets.

If I run this snippet

```
from deap import creator, base, tools
import random

creator.create("Fitness", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0, 1.0))
creator.create("Individual", set, fitness=creator.Fitness)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_item", random.randrange, 5)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
    toolbox.attr_item, 3)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.population(n=5)
```

then I get the following output:

```
Out: [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 4}, {0}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2}]
```

with individuals of length 1, 2 or 3.

However, if I run the next snippet, only changing `set` to `list` in the fourth line

```
from deap import creator, base, tools
import random

creator.create("Fitness", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0, 1.0))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.Fitness)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_item", random.randrange, 5)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
    toolbox.attr_item, 3)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.population(n=5)
```

then all the individuals have the same length.

```
Out: [[2, 2, 4], [0, 1, 0], [2, 2, 4], [1, 4, 1], [2, 2, 0]]
```

Is it possible to build a population of individuals which are lists of various lengths?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question, but I think that what might be happening has to do with the difference between a `set` and a `list`. Since a set is an ordered structure of distinct elements, if e.g the 5 random numbers `1, 3, 1, 5, 4` are put into a set, the result will be `{1, 3, 4, 5}`, a set of length 4. However, if 5 random numbers are put into a list, the result will always be a list of length 5.

This is why the first example with sets results in individuals of various lengths, but the second example with lists results in individuals with all the same lengths.